# How to hide programs from Programs and Features?

Tags: windows-7

I installed some games on my work computer and I want to remove them from the Program and Features list, without uninstalling them. Any ideas?

Comment: if this is to "get around" your work's IT support finding out that you have games on your work machine (I'm assuming this is not tecnically allowed or part of your AUP) there are many other ways. If this is legit, can you not run some from a USB drive?

Comment: well i have counter strike on my work pc and i do not want the boss to find out

Comment: note that auditing programs have... their ways of finding out what's installed.

Comment: It might be a better idea to actually do your job and play games at home. It would save you lots of hassle and make you more productive

Comment: "and make you more productive..." ...and less likely to be sacked.

Comment: -1 Because your boss follows superuser.com.

Comment: -1 for "Just get the hell to work."

Comment: I love this kind of question, it brings out the best in all of us. ;->

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The programs showing in the Programs and Features list are generated from the registry keys under:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

Answer (score 3):

Download ccleaner and follow "Option 2" on this [document](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/86721-programs-features-remove-uninstall-entry.html)

Remove Uninstall Entry using "CCleaner" Program

1. If you have not already, download and install the latest version of the CCleaner.

2. Click on the CCleaner shortcut icon either on your desktop or in the Start Menu to run the program.

3. Click on the Tools button on the left.

4. Select the uninstall entry and click the Delete Entry button to remove it from the Programs and Features uninstall list.

5. Click on the X in the upper right corner to close CCleaner when done.

Answer (score -1):

Go in Run Command, enter regedit and visit following location:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`

Click on uninstall and find the main root key folder under uninstall. Delete all the key folder related which you want to hide the application.